# How can get current country name and state in WordPress function

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I want to use `geoplugin`. but current Geo plugin show data in `json`. But how can use this `json` code in `WordPress function`
[hear example json](http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp)

```
{
  "geoplugin_request": "122.180.85.165",
  "geoplugin_status": 200,
  "geoplugin_delay": "2ms",
  "geoplugin_credit": "Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href='http://www.maxmind.com'>http://www.maxmind.com</a>.",
  "geoplugin_city": "Ludhiana",
  "geoplugin_region": "Punjab",
  "geoplugin_regionCode": "PB",
  "geoplugin_regionName": "Punjab",
  "geoplugin_areaCode": "",
  "geoplugin_dmaCode": "",
  "geoplugin_countryCode": "IN",
  "geoplugin_countryName": "India",
  "geoplugin_inEU": 0,
  "geoplugin_continentCode": "AS",
  "geoplugin_continentName": "Asia",
  "geoplugin_latitude": "30.9",
  "geoplugin_longitude": "75.85",
  "geoplugin_locationAccuracyRadius": "100",
  "geoplugin_timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "geoplugin_currencyCode": "INR",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol": "&#8360;",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8": "₨",
  "geoplugin_currencyConverter": 67.9875
}
```

Comment: What keeps you from running [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to parse that JSON array into a PHP array?

Comment: i know `json_decode` but how can use in WordPress and how can create WordPress function. please explain me

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Wordpress is written in PHP, and you can use any PHP method directly

Comment: Try this link http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php

Comment: i want to get current user location on my site

Comment: you can get the data using file_get_contents();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this. hope this will help you!!

```
function getusercountrycode()
{
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp? 
ip=".$ip,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => false
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json_a=json_decode($result,true);
$countrycode = $json_a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
return $countrycode;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need this code. it's working according to my need. thank you @asif.

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this

```
function geo_location(){ 
  $result = file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp'); 
  $resultArr = json_decode($result); 
  echo 'Country ='. $resultArr->geoplugin_countryName; 
} 

geo_location();
```

Comment: Thank you for reply @George  please check my code not working

----------

function geo_location(){

  $result = file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp');
 $resultArr = json_decode($result);
 echo 'Country ='. $resultArr['geoplugin_countryName'];
 
}
geo_location();

Answer (score 1):

TRY This also

```
 echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])));
```

it will give you an array